# Is it possible to create .bak file of a database in sql server with the .mdf and .ldf file of the the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi So I put myself in a situation where I can no longer access ms sql server in a vm that I have created. My question is if it is possible to create  a backup file(.bak) outside of the sql server by perhaps levering the databases .ldf and/or .mdf file?

Comment: you can attach them using mdf and ldf to any other server and take backup 
 https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

Comment: What have you tried to regain control of the Sql Server instance?

Comment: @MarnixvanValen I installed this tool called TSPlus which is an improved version of mstsc and accidentally clicked on the client.exe file when I was trying to robocopy it over to my client machine. When I attempted to log off the session, it will log off the vm. I tried to restart the vm, delete the client.exe file remotely, and even tried to uninstall TSPlus remotely. My only option i to recover the databases on that server and spin up a new server.

Comment: Why don't use mdf and ldf directly for porting your db to another server? You can migrate your database both by restoring (from bak) or by attaching (mdf + ldf) it on another server.